# Как упростить массовое выключение кнопок?

Tags: c#, winforms

Как максимально упростить подобный код, ведь уверен, что можно 1-2 строками разобраться?

```
textBox1.Enabled = false;
textBox2.Enabled = false;
textBox3.Enabled = false;
textBox4.Enabled = false;
textBox5.Enabled = false;
textBox6.Enabled = false;
```

Циклом "прогнать" ведь тут не получится, т.к. это название экземпляра. Каковы есть решения?

Comment: А зачем вам названия экземпляра. Сделайте массив указателей на экземпляры. Или тут так нельзя ?

Comment: @Mike как вариант, но по кол-ву строк кода ничего особо не изменится, если это делать так (хотя могу ошибаться) Мне кажется, тут есть выход проще.

Comment: пожалуйста, в одну строчку :) `for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) { FindControl("textBox" + i.ToString()).Enabled = false; }` Только это плохой код, и я предпочел бы 6 строчек кода в вопросе.

Comment: @Igor спасибо! расскажите, пожалуйста, чем чревато писать так? т.е. чем плох?

п.с. Mike так имел в виду вроде
`TextBox[] tBoxes = { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4, textBox5 };
            for (int i = 0; i < tBoxes.Length; i++)
            {
                tBoxes[i].Enabled = false;
            }`

Comment: @DmitryShulga а почему не `foreach` тогда уж?

Answer (score 3):

Перетянуть эти текстбоксы на один контейнер (ЕМНИП в винформ есть панел). Тогда будет такой код.

```
OptionalPanel.Enabled = false;
```

Так вы будете выключать всю панель, а не каждый компонент по отдельности.

Comment: А что, они будут выглядеть "disabled"?

Comment: @Igor серенькие, неактивные - это "disabled". Я просто уже не помню винфом.

Comment: У этого способа есть существенный недостаток, отключится абсолютно все в этой панели, даже то, что необходимо оставить включеным

Comment: @Dmitry Это не "недостаток" - это "фича"

Answer (score 2):

пожалуйста, в одну строчку :)

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) 
{ 
  FindControl("textBox" + i.ToString()).Enabled = false; 
}
```

Только это плохой код, и я предпочел бы 6 строчек кода в вопросе.

1. Оставлять названия компонентов "от Visual Studio" - некрасиво по отношению к тому, кто будет поддерживать этот код. Каждый раз вспоминать, что `textBox3` - это название улицы в адресе - увольте.
2. Код работает исходя из предположения, что все компоненты лежат на одном родителе, как только какой-то из них переложат на что-то другое, `FindControl` вернет `null`. Можно проверять результат вызова `FindControl` на `null`, но это еще хуже - код просто тихо не будет работать.

Answer (score 2):

Нашел такой вариант (добавив все в контейнер):

```
foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls) {
    if (c is TextBox)
        c.Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: panel1.Controls.Where(n => n is TextBox).Select(n => {n.Enabled = false; return n;});   //одна строка :)

Comment: @Mirdin проект на .NET 2.x ... ругается на Where()

Comment: Это LINQ - он по моему с 3 версии заработал, или 3.5?

Comment: @Mirdin, LINQ с 3-ей версии языка C# появился. К версии фреймворка он отношения не имеет вообще. При таргете ".NET Framework 2.0" - да, вполне себе работает. Просто скорей всего у автора в проект не добавлена сборка System.Core(она появилась в одном из сервис-паков), и/или не указан using пространства имен System.Linq.

Comment: @Mirdin вы забыли `.ToList()` вызвать. Без него не заработает - вычисления-то ленивые. Кроме того, `Select` с посторонними эффектами - это антипаттерн.

Answer (score 2):

Добавляем в форму следующее свойство:

```
private bool _textBoxesEnabled;
public bool TextBoxesEnabled {
  get { return _textBoxesEnabled; }
  set { 
    _textBoxesEnabled = value;
    if (TextBoxesEnabledChanged != null)
      TextBoxesEnabledChanged(this, new EventArgs())
  }
}
public event EventHandler TextBoxesEnabledChanged;
```

Теперь свойство `Enabled` текстбоксов можно забиндить на это `TextBoxesEnabled`.